# Unity's particles look dull (mobile/additive)

Tags: unity, particles

[image]

I've created a couple VFX for a project and exported them as a unitypackage. Now, I want to showcase each effect and created a new project for that. However, the particles all look very dull and it seems like they're not using the additive shader of the particle correctly. I've tried to mess around in the project quality settings, but nothing has changed. They're both using the default URP. I've also checked the camera settings for both projects, but I think that's the wrong place either way, because they look wrong in the scene view, as well. I'm not sure where else to look?

The right particle system is displaying the effect correctly (bright with transparency) while the left one is the same system after importing to another project. I want the left system to look like the one on the right.

Edit: Even when just display 2 particles being spawned on top of each other in prefab view, the current project is much duller. It doesn't look like additive blend at all. [image]

Comment: Looks to me like a draw order difference. Is the halo being drawn in front of the rays on the left, and behind on the right?

Comment: @DMGregory the sorting does not make any difference. I've added another screenshot in the original post. Both particle systems show 2 particles on top of each other with additive blend.

Comment: Sounds like you should walk us through a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example - give us a step-by-step breakdown of everything we need to do to produce the correct-looking particle effect, starting from a new empty project, so we can isolate the specific step where the problem arises and test potential solutions.

Comment: The particles behave as expected in a brand new project. A step-by-step would include to paint a new particle texture with a bright core and gradient in radial direction. Then use the mobile/particles/additive shader for these particles and spawn two yellow colored particles on top of each other. I must say that creating a brand new project is a workaround for me. I guess some settings went wrong when I upgraded my old project to the latest Unity version.